# InteliJ trustStore VM options not being set

Tags: java

I'm trying to set `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` to the correct values, however when I pass them as VM options they're not being set.

I pass them like this:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
-Djavax.net.ssl=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="test.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="abc123"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType= "JKS"
```

When I set them through `System.setProperty`, it works fine

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "test.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "abc123");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
```

I've double checked all the properties and values, and in both cases they're the same. I do understand that `System.setProperty` achieves the same, but the trust store and password differ from environment to environment, so I would prefer to pass them as VM options instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add VM option at "Run/Debug Configuration"
[image]
then start your application, in console you can see you jdk
[image]
click the jdk, can see the vm detail
[image]

Comment: I have done this, and can see the options in the logs. However when passing it as VM options it's throwing errors saying the keystore cannot be found.

Comment: How you get the var? you can use `@Value` to inject env to a var, and passing it. @liquid5109

Comment: It's a VM option, why do i need to get the variable? I just want to set it through the VM options.